# Использовать рандомно сгенерированное значение несколько раз

Tags: postman

Люди добрые, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Есть ли возможность использовать одно автоматически сгенерированное значение UUID в разных частях запроса?
[image: Пробовал сохранять в переменную, но postman всё равно выдаёт разные значения. PS скрин просто для примера]

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт
Если назначить переменную через Pre-request Script, то работает как нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]